# Is it possible to show a view's page in the admin overlay?

Tags: views, modal-dialogs

I created a view with a page display, which has an path alias, say: node/*/something/somethingelse
Now I would like that, if someone clicks on a link leading to the above path, the view's page is shown in the admin overlay. I tried following:

```
function custom_api_admin_paths_alter(&$paths) {
  $path['node/*/something/somethingelse'] = TRUE;
}
```

But it does not work. What did I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It may be a bit late and unfortunately I can not assist with your php script but you can try the [Overlay Paths](https://drupal.org/project/overlay_paths) module which can achieve something similar to what you are trying to do.

It kind of did what I needed and I say kind of because it does not work that well with Views.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by [`hook_admin_paths_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_admin_paths_alter/7.x) function

```
function YOURMODULE_admin_paths_alter(&$paths) {
  // Treats your view page as administrative.
  $paths[''node/*/something/somethingelse''] = TRUE;
   }
```

I remember, I've used the abouve method to achieve the same requirement.

Hope it helps.